# How to optimize the following perl code?

Tags: perl

In the below code I tried to print every line along with its line number. Is there any other way to optimize the below code using Perl?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
open my $fh,"<","exercise.csv";
while(<$fh>)
{
   print "$.=====>$_";
}
close $fh;
```

Comment: It depends what you mean by _optimize_. You can make it more _concise_ by using certain language features. The whole loop can be condensed into `print "$.=====>$_" while <$fh>;` and you don't have to do the `close $fh` because it will automatically close the filehandle when `$fh` goes out of scope. You should include `or die $!` to catch errors from your `open` (and in theory also your `close`, as that could fail, but we've just removed it anyway). But that's really a codereview, which should go on [codereview.se], not here.

Comment: Maybe we can benchmark between the print with variable interpolaton, as in posted question, and print with variable concatenation as in print $. .'====>'.$_;

Comment: If you redirect the output to a file instead of printing to the terminal, it may run faster, especially if it is a large file, since the terminal does not need to render everything....  `perl my_script.pl > output`

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Is your program running too slowly? Is it taking up too much memory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

When you're optimising, you look at things that are less efficient ways of accomplishing the goal. That's often algorithmic, and looking at where looping is occurring is a good start.

But then there's resource usage optimisation - disk IO is often the most expensive operation - but you *need* to do all the IO that you're doing, and you're not doing any redundant IO.

And sometimes - system calls or 'shelling out' to other binaries (via `system` or backticks) can incur overhead. But you don't do that either.

Basically - your code is just not complicated enough to have any significant inefficiencies.